# Can't access a template value or struct value inside range in Go template

Tags: go, go-templates

I am passing a struct while executing a template. I can't access the string variable inside struct while iterating through slice variable which is part of same struct.

I tried using $ as per the prefix while accessing the variable.
I also tried creating a variable in the template itself and calling it inside range. I can't see that this new variable is accessible outside the range but not inside.

```
package main
type landing_page Struct {
    Login_user string
    Versions_tagged []oradatabase.Tag_versions
}

package oradatabase
// partial code
type Tag_version struct {
     User_id string,
     Rel_name string
}
```

All these structs are initialized and has value assigned correctly as I can access the values outside range within template without any issue.

```html
template : landing_page.html
Trial - 1
---------
<table>
<thead><tr>
<th>h1</th>
<th>h2</th>
<th>h3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{{ range .Versions_tagged}}
<tr>
<td>{{.User_id}}</td>
<td>{{.Rel_Name}}</td>
<td>{{$.Login_user}}</td>
</tr>
{{end}}
</tbody>
</table>

Trial -2
---------
{{ $login_user := .Login_user}}
<table>
<thead><tr>
<th>h1</th>
<th>h2</th>
<th>h3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{{ range .Versions_tagged}}
<tr>
<td>{{.User_id}}</td>
<td>{{.Rel_Name}}</td>
<td>{{$login_user}}</td>
</tr>
{{end}}
</tbody>
</table>
```

With both these trial - the login_user inside range is coming is null ( no value) while is accessible outside. Can't figure out what's wrong.
Go version :1.11.4

The value of variable Login_user should be available inside the range in template. There is no error on console. It simply doesn't print anything for Login_user inside range and loop also terminate as that stage.

Comment: Both your attempts should work. The error is most likely somewhere else. If you want help, post a [mcve].

Comment: I have added the definition of structs. will that help? Since I am using struct from another package ( oradatabase) . Could that be an issue?

Comment: Show the Go code that executes the template.